# Joint convergence in distribution and independence

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, independence

I am having some trouble getting my head round independence of random variables when it comes to convergence in distribution.

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are i.i.d. standard normal, and $\{Y_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ are i.i.d standard normal, independent of the $X_n$. Then, $X_n \to X$ and $Y_n \to Y$ as $n \to \infty$ where $\to$ denotes convergence in distribution, and $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed.

What, if anything can we say about the independence of $X$ and $Y$? On one hand, it seems as if $X$ and $Y$ should be independent but on the other hand, it also holds that $Y_n \to X$, and $X$ is clearly not independent of $X$!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nothing can be said about the independence of $X$ and $Y$, because $X$ can be taken to equal $Y$. Remember: distributional limits of random variables are not unique as random variables, but only as distributions (i.e, as measures in the pushforward).

Comment: @Shalop Thanks for your comment! That does make sense. Does anything change if I consider $(X_n, Y_n) \to (X, Y) $ instead, with $X_n$ and $Y_n$ as stated in my question? In this case it seems important to know whether or not $X$ and $Y$ are independent, since it will determine the distribution of $(X, Y)$ (via the covariance). Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, in that case you can deduce independence of $X$ and $Y$; the point being that the distributional limit of bivariate standard normals is itself a bivariate standard normal, hence has independent components.